# Correct CSS to display html form elements in certain order?

Tags: html, css, forms, smarty

```
    <input type="checkbox" ID="RecquireFacebookInvitesCB" />Require
    <select>
    {section name=foo start=5 loop=50 step=1}
        <option value="{$smarty.section.foo.index}">{$smarty.section.foo.index}</option>
    {/section}
    </select>
    this many Facebook invites before entering sweepstakes
```

[image]

I have the above html (with smarty-php formatting tags) that produces two form elements and some text as displayed in my screen shot. I'd like to make this display as:

```
[CHECKBOX] Require [SELECTION LIST] Facebook invites before entering sweepstakes
```

I have my own ideas on how to implement this but I'm wondering what the best approach would be. Thanks!

Comment: In the screen shot, selection list is first while in display that you want selection list is third? (1) put it in a div, change the markup order, float left. (2) put it in a div, position relative, and each item position absolute

Comment: @JAA149, I tried that - but making each element's position absolute inside of a relatively positioned div seems to make all the elements overlay on top of each other.

Comment: Yeah what gives? The order is already there! Check if some CSS code somewhere is effecting the order.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, I managed to figure out what was going on using google chrome's attribute inspector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ID="RecquireFacebookInvitesCB" /><label for="RecquireFacebookInvitesCB">Require</label>
<select>
{section name=foo start=5 loop=50 step=1}
    <option value="{$smarty.section.foo.index}">{$smarty.section.foo.index}</option>
{/section}
</select>
this many Facebook invites before entering sweepstakes
```